$E[X\mid U,V]$ with dependent random variables
Let $(X,Y,Z)$ be a three-dimensional random variable with density function $f(x,y,z)=\frac{2}{3}(x+y+z)$ on $0<x,y,z<1$, $U=\min(X,Y,Z)$, $V=\max(X,Y,Z)$. Calculate $E[X\mid U,V]$.
I think the answer is $\frac{14U^2+26UV+14V^2}{27(U+V)}$, but I'm not sure.

You can share your calculations and people can help you verify

If this answer was correct (which looks plausible) again, I would like to respect you as the "Ramanujan in the field of conditional expectation" :)

Thanks @Zhanxiong, I admire you too.

@Speltzu Can we have a private chat here?

@Zhanxiong  Yes, tell me.

@Speltzu Please enter the room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/155998/conditional-expectation?tab=general
